# How to make password-less login work

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I generated a key and copied it to my target:

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id username@hostname
```

I left the the location of the key as default and did not set any passphrase.

For a small while after that, I was able to `ssh username@hostname` without being prompted for a password, and then it stopped working for some reason.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/ssh/info … Let's make this a reference question that we can close others as a duplicate of.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If public key authentication doesn't work: make sure that on the server side, your home directory (`~`), the `~/.ssh` directory, and the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, are all writable *only by their owner*. In particular, none of them must be writable by the group (even if the user is alone in the group). `chmod 755` or `chmod 700` is ok, `chmod 770` is not.

What to check when something is wrong:

- Run `ssh -vvv` to see a lot of debugging output. If you post a question asking why you can't connect with ssh, include this output (you may want to anonymize host and user names).
- If you can, check the server logs, typically in `/var/log/daemon.log` or `/var/log/auth.log` or similar.
- If public key authentication isn't working, check the permissions again, especially the group bit (see above).

Comment: Hi, why should `authorized_keys` not be writable by the group ? Does SSH reject this because of security concerns ?

Comment: @YdobEmos Anyone who can write to `authorized_keys` can add their own key there and thus log into the account. So only the user must be allowed. (Having the file group-writable is actually safe if no other user is in that group, but that's difficult to detect reliably when group memberships can come from network databases.)

Answer (score 1):

The home directory of the target was `755 drwxr-xr-x`. Changing it to be group-writable `775 drwxrwxr-x` broke the password-less setup.

Comment: Same problem did not solved it yet.

Comment: You mean you can't get password-less login work, even after making the directory group-writable?

Comment: YES - please see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/208152/11085 , CentOS 7 64-bit where i am trying to login with my id_rsa keys but its always failing.

Answer (score 0):

After making sure permissions were correct, resent keys, it was still not working.

Then I stumbled on this which I had not done previously and had not seen anyone mention.

**[Unable to use -o allow_other with sshfs (option enabled in fuse.conf)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37168/unable-to-use-o-allow-other-with-sshfs-option-enabled-in-fuse-conf)**

After enabling I ran my sshfs commands without sudo and it all worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming RHEL/CentOS, and assuming you have admin access to the remote server where user `newuser` wants to ssh to.

Obtain `newuser's` existing `id_rsa.pub` and have ready.

Follow the steps:

```
useradd newuser
mkdir /home/newuser/.ssh
vi /home/newuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
# copy newuser's id_rsa.pub into authorized_keys and save
chmod 640 /home/newuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 700 /home/newuser/.ssh/
chmod 700 /home/newuser/
chown newuser:newuser -R /home/newuser/
```

Have `newuser` attempt to log in.