# Unable to use -o allow_other with sshfs (option enabled in fuse.conf)

Tags: ssh, sshfs, fuse

I have the following on my `/etc/fuse.conf` file:

```
# Set the maximum number of FUSE mounts allowed to non-root users.                       
# The default is 1000.                                                                   
#                                                                                        
#mount_max = 1000                                                                        

# Allow non-root users to specify the 'allow_other' or 'allow_root'                      
# mount options.                                                                         
#                                                                                        
user_allow_other
```

But when I try to mount a remote path with the option `allow_other`:

```
> sshfs name@server:/remote/path /local/path -o allow_other
```

I get:

```
fusermount: failed to open /etc/fuse.conf: Permission denied
fusermount: option allow_other only allowed if 'user_allow_other' is set in /etc/fuse.conf
```

I have triple checked and the option `user_allow_other` is uncommented in my `fuse.conf`,as I copied above.

I have also executed `sudo adduser my_user_name fuse` (not sure if this is needed though), but I still get the same problem.

Why is it not parsing the `/etc/fuse.conf` file correctly?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A better solution might be to add the user to the **fuse** group, i.e.:

```
addgroup <username> fuse
```

Comment: Then log out and log back in!

Comment: And add existing user to fuse as secondary group: `usermod -a -G  existing_user fuse` # in case `addgroup` is not present on your system

Comment: on ubuntu 20.04 i tried that but got `addgroup: The group `fuse' does not exist.`

Comment: Group fuse was eliminated after Debian 8.

Answer (score 28):

Given the message `failed to open /etc/fuse.conf: Permission denied`, I suggest

```
chmod a+r /etc/fuse.conf
```

Comment: This is the correct answer

Comment: @MountainX it would be nice to know why exactly

Comment: It will be nice to have the script to revert it, for people that doesn't understand chmod at all ...