# Unable to force passphraseless ssh authentication while port forwarding

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, openssh, port-forwarding, sshd

I'm completely at a loss as to what is preventing my local machine from authenticating the connection that is being forwarded from the remote server.

I've read a ton of the posts on here regarding this and man, I swear I've tried damn near everything.

The guide I've been following can be found here: http://www.zeespencer.com/articles/building-a-remote-pairing-setup/

Basically where I'm stuck at is in forcing passwordless authentication. If I allow passwords in sshd_config, when I connect to pair@pair-server I am prompted for my local user password and am able to login remotely, so I am being forwarded. But, as soon as I turn it off, I get the following

```
   λ   ssh pair@pair-server 
Permission denied (publickey).
Connection to pair-server closed.
```

Verbose output here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0c2b3892596d5ded6abb

I currently have my local user key.pub in pair@pair-server's .ssh/authorized_keys which are command directed to ssh back to localhost. pair@pair-server has it's own key, on my computer I've added pair@pair-server's key.pub to .ssh/authorized_keys.

Seemingly relevant lines in sshd_config:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication no
UseLogin no
```

account and session settings in /etc/pam.d/sshd on pair-server:

```
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
```

password-auth configuration:

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
```

.ssh permissions:

```
node-v0.8.25|ruby-1.9.3-p392|~|
   λ   ls -lhd .ssh
drwx------ 2 dan dan 4.0K Jul 10 19:49 .ssh
```

OS:

```
   λ   lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.04
Release:    13.04
Codename:   raring
```

OpenSSH Client Version:

```
   λ   ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
```

Comment: could you post: 
  * the output of '$ ls -lhd .ssh/' ?
  * OS and version of client and server?

thanks!

Comment: @Mario sure thing, added the output to my question

Comment: [Are all three permissions (`~`, `~/.ssh`, `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`) correct on the server side?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16978/how-to-make-password-less-login-work) What messages appear in `/var/log/auth.log` on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for trying to help everyone, really appreciate it. Anyways, it seems ssh-agent was the culprit. I forgot I have to check if there is previously spawned instances of it already running before spawning my own. I had something like 9 of them running. I don't know much bash, but here where the 3 lines I added to my .bashrc on the remote server that got it working:

```
pkill ssh-agent
exec "$(ssh-agent)"
ssh-add $HOME/.ssh/pair_key
```

Answer (score 1):

Are your permissions OK? .ssh must be 700.

Comment: Yep, added .ssh's permissions to my question. All files inside of .ssh are 600 as well.