# How do I access a login through ssh when there is no password set?

Tags: ssh

I would like to be able to access my home machine's account over ssh from a remote desktop.  It allows me to connect when I say ssh uname@ip_addr, but it then prompts for a password.

This account has no password set up.  Is there some way to simply connect with no password? Any help would be appreciated.  (A reference to a line on a man page or would be an acceptable answer.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use authorized keys.
Enable it in sshd_config

```
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

then: if you allready have you have your rsa.pub, in case:

reach your youser's home .ssh

```
cd ~/.ssh
```

generate your rsa keypair

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

append your id_rsa.pub to remote user's authorized_keys and login

Comment: I'm curious if you have tried this and got it working. I just tried it on my system, and it still asked me for a password.

Comment: @spuder, trying using -v to get more information, and checking ssh logs on both systems. Chances are it'll tell you what ssh is upset about.

Comment: @spuder [Usually, it's a permission problem.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16978/how-to-make-password-less-login-work)

Comment: @spunder, can you do ssh to your account on the same machine, most of distros don't allow you ssh to an account with empty password

Comment: Checked and it's working (local on local) on ubuntu 12.some.
I'll check again on a remote srv.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have these settings in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Of course, you will have to setup a public key on your server and save it as ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and use the private key generated to login - there are several tutorials online detailing this process. Once this is setup, you can SSH to your remote machine like this:

`ssh -i /path/to/private/key user@hostname`