# Fedora, where to put my ssh keys to login?

Tags: ssh, fedora, ssh-keygen

I just recently started a VPS using Fedora.  Upon creation of the VPS I was asked if I wanted to use SSH keys (which I did). Now, to connect as root to the VPS, I do not need to enter a password.

Now I want to create a pair (or just reuse the same key) for `user1` for use while using ssh.  First I tried to paste the `id_rsa.pub` folder while logged in as `user1` in the  `~/.ssh/` folder.

- Still asks for password upon ssh

Then I added a `authorized_keys` file that was identical to the `id_rsa.pub` file.

- Still asks for password upon ssh

Then I `chmod` the permissions to the `.ssh` folder to `644` however, when I try to ssh login as `user1`.

- Still asks for password upon ssh

How can I use the same public ssh key on a user account that I have for the root account.  Where to I put these files, and what is the difference between having a `id_rsa.pub` file and an `authorized_keys` file?

Comment: [Have you checked all the permissions?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16978/how-to-make-password-less-login-work) The `.ssh` directory must be 700 (`drwx------`), the `authorized_keys` file must be 644 or 640 or 600 (`-rw-r--r--` or `-rw-r-----` or `-rw-------`), and your home directory must not be group-writable. If you can't figure out whether the permissions are correct, post the output of `ls -ld ~ ~/.ssh ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server and `ls -ld ~ ~/.ssh ~/.ssh/id_rsa` on the client.

Comment: This is correct. I did have appropriate permissions on the `.ssh` directory. That fixed it.

Also, can you tell me what file actually gets checked? is it the `authorized_keys` or the `id_rsa.pub` file?

Comment: The `id_rsa.pub` file is never read by `ssh` (but it's useful to keep it around to easily determine where a public key is coming from). The server reads `authorized_keys` and the client needs `id_rsa`.

Comment: when you say "to keep around" - if I set up keys on another computer I just append the key to the existing `id_rsa.pub` and `authorized_keys` files correct? Is `ssh` somehow able to parse the files to read the different keys?

Comment: The SSH server reads `authorized_keys`. To authorize multiple keys, just append the `.pub` files to it. Each line in that file represents one authorized key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the option `-i` to specify to ssh which identity file it should use.

Also have you checked with `ssh - v` what really happen? I mean the keys are really not used or are they used but doesn't match?