# Linux - Cannot connect using ssh key

Tags: linux, ssh, timeout

I used to connect normally to the website on digitalocean using ssh keys and it works normally. Currently I tried to connect and suddenly I keep getting: `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out`.

I tried to run the ssh command again using `-vvv` and I got the following:

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ip [ip] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/safwany/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/safwany/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/safwany/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/safwany/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/safwany/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/safwany/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/safwany/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/safwany/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out
```

Any idea what is the cause for such error and how to fix it?

Update:
I ran `ls -al ~/.ssh` and got the following:

```
total 160
drwx------   15 safwany  staff    510 Jul 12 23:52 .
drwx------+ 109 safwany  staff   3706 Jul 13 00:02 ..
-rwx------    1 safwany  staff   2437 Jul 13 00:02 authorized_keys
-rw-------    1 safwany  staff   1679 Mar 17  2015 digitalocean
-rw-r--r--    1 safwany  staff    413 Mar 17  2015 digitalocean.pub
-rw-------    1 safwany  staff   1679 Mar  4  2015 fortrabbit
-rw-r--r--    1 safwany  staff    413 Mar  4  2015 fortrabbit.pub
-rwx------    1 safwany  staff   1766 Nov 21  2014 github_rsa
-rwx------    1 safwany  staff    404 Nov 21  2014 github_rsa.pub
-rw-------    1 safwany  staff   1675 Jul  1  2015 id_boot2docker
-rw-r--r--    1 safwany  staff    413 Jul  1  2015 id_boot2docker.pub
-rw-------    1 safwany  staff   1675 Nov 23  2014 id_rsa
-rw-------    1 safwany  staff    381 Jul 12 23:16 id_rsa.pub
-rw-------    1 safwany  staff  17736 Jul 10 17:11 known_hosts
-rw-------    1 safwany  staff  15268 Feb 21 22:44 known_hosts.old
```

Comment: This might be a file permissions issue: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235565/cant-login-to-a-remote-machine-with-key

Comment: @John1024 Could you elaborate more? I can't find a clear answer

Comment: `ssh` is very picky about file permissions.  Can you run `ls -al ~/.ssh` and show us the results.

Comment: @John1024 Check the update

Comment: Those permissions and the file list look good to me.   My next thought is to check on the cause of the message `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out`.  Do you have access to the server's logs to see if its ssh is up and running and saw your connection attempt?

Comment: The most common location for `sshd` logs is `/var/log/secure`, you can grep it for your own public IP (connecting party) to find the relevant pieces.

Comment: `Operation timed out` -- not a permission issue. Firewall or network problem. Can you ping the server? Can you connect to other ports? Do you have enough free space on the drive?