# Setup SSH login using public key in GoFlex Home

Tags: ssh, nas

I am trying to setup SSH public keys to login to my GoFlex Home 2TB. These are the steps I took

1. Copy my public key to `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys`
2. Modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to allow public key authentication and point to the `authorized_keys` file
3. End the SSH session
4. login to `goflexhome.loal` and reboot the NAS device

### Details of the client system:

- OS: Linux Mint 17.3
- Network type: LAN (Ethernet)

### Details of the host system (NAS)

- OS: hipserv2 (Linux based by Seagate, default OS in GoFlex Home)

When I try to initiate the ssh session I get a password prompt instead of using my private key to login

### File Permissions at /home/user/.ssh

```
-bash-3.2$ ls -la
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 user root 232 Mar 18 16:49 .
dr-xr-x--- 7 user www  616 Mar 18 16:48 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user root 746 Mar 18 16:49 authorized_keys
-bash-3.2$
```

### SSH verbose

Full [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/ZSe31bqS).

Excerpt:

```
ssh -v user_hipserv2_seagateplug_XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX@goflexhome.local
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available
...
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: user@user-system
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user_hipserv2_seagateplug_XXX@goflexhome.local's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to goflexhome.local ([10.42.0.12]:22).
```

Comment: did you tried ssh in verbose mode to see if keys are used at all, or just rejected: ssh -vvv user@server. Check also ownership of your .ssh directory.

Comment: You think when you say GoFlex NAS, everyone knows what it is and probably 99% of people here don't. So, let's start with some questions: Where are you trying to login from: A Widows PC or Linux terminal ? When you say you modified `sshd_config` are you referring to this file residin on your NAS or your local machine ? Also please post the output of this command, run on the NAS device `ls -al /home/user/.ssh`

Comment: On hipserv2 system, do you have a login, if you do, login to this box and please post the output from `ls -al /home/user/.ssh` where user needs to be replaced by your username on hipserv2 box

Comment: Hi @MelBurslan, I've updated the OP

Comment: @mmmint, I've updated the OP with the verbose output, my system prompts me for the keyphrase but continues on to the password validation

Comment: What appears in the server logs when you try to log in? That's usually where the clues are. For generic troubleshooting, see [How to make password-less login work](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16978/how-to-make-password-less-login-work)

Answer (score 0):

on hipserve2 machine, please run

```
chmod 700 /home/user/.ssh
chmod 600 /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

and try again

Comment: Thank you for the response but changing the permissions did not work.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the contents of `/var/log/auth.log` on the **server** to find the issue why key authentication is skipped at all.

In the past I came across some tutorials that describe how to achieve a ssh password-less setup, but some are sadly wrong.
 Let's start over again, and check every step:

1. **FROM CLIENT** - Generate key: `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
   Public and private key (`id_rsa.pub` and `id_rsa`) will be automatically stored in the `~/.ssh/` directory.
   Setup will be easier if you use an empty passphrase. If you are not willing to do that, then still follow this guide, but also check the bullet point below.
2. **FROM CLIENT** - Copy public key to **server** : `ssh-copy-id user@server`
   Client public key will be copied to **server's location** `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
3. **FROM CLIENT** - Connect to server: `ssh user@server`

Now, if it's still not working after the described 3 steps, lets try the following:

- Check `~/ssh` folder permissions in **client** and **server** machine.
- Check `/etc/ssh/ssd_config` in the **server** to ensure that `RSAAuthentication`, `PubkeyAuthentication` and `UsePAM` options aren't disabled, as they are enabled by default with `yes`.
- If you entered a passphrase while generating your client key, then you may try `ssh-agent` & `ssh-add` to achieve password-less connections in your session.
- Check the contents of `/var/log/auth.log` on the **server** to find the issue why key authentication is skipped at all.